# Python Binance Futures Take Profit and Stop Loss order API Error 2021 Order would immediately trigger

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I have written a trading bot working on futures account for margin trading. The piece of code that I shared below worked fine for just one time. Then it started to give the following error:

> APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger

The problem is when I copy and paste this piece of code(part related to open position and give take profit and stop loss orders) to a new file and run it, it works fine but gives an error in the bot. I couldn't find the cause of the problem.

```
if currentdiffer > 0:
                
                    buy_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol='SOLBUSD',
                                                            side='BUY',
                                                            type ='MARKET',
                                                            quantity = qty, 
                                                            positionSide='LONG')
               
                    poisiton = "LONG"
                    
                    stopprice = currentprice - (value*1.2) 
                    takeprofit = currentprice + (value*1.2) 
                    
                    stopprice = round(stopprice,2)
                    takeprofit = round(takeprofit,2)
                    
                    print("Take profit : ", takeprofit)
                    print("Stop price : ", stopprice)
                    
                    tp_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol='SOLBUSD',
                                                            side='SELL',
                                                            positionSide='LONG',
                                                            type ='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET',
                                                            timeInForce='GTE_GTC',
                                                            quantity = qty,
                                                            stopPrice=stopprice,
                                                            workingType='MARK_PRICE'
                                                            )

                    sl_order = client.futures_create_order(symbol='SOLBUSD',
                                                            side='SELL',
                                                            positionSide='LONG',
                                                            type ='STOP_MARKET',
                                                            timeInForce='GTE_GTC',
                                                            quantity = qty,
                                                            stopPrice=takeprofit,
                                                            workingType='MARK_PRICE'
                                                            )
```

Comment: What part of "Order would immediately trigger." is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

It is because  you set stoploss or take profit less than market price.
For example for Buy position, stop loss should be bigger than market price.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you messed up with the parameter that you send

Check the API Docs. It's all there

```
For TRAILING_STOP_MARKET, if you got such error code.
{"code": -2021, "msg": "Order would immediately trigger."}
means that the parameters you send do not meet the following requirements:

BUY: activationPrice should be smaller than latest price.
SELL: activationPrice should be larger than latest price.
```

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade